# How can I use re's special characters when splitting a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose I have this variable, named `string`.

```
string = "Hello(There|World!!"
```

Since I want to split on multiple delimiters, I'm using `re.split()` to do the job. Unfortunately, this string contains special characters used by the `re` module. I don't want to use `re.escape()` because that would escape the exclamation points too. How can I split on `re`'s special characters without using `re.escape()`?

Comment: What are you doing so far - and what is the expected outcome - how do they differ?

Comment: @SteveJohnson What would you expected output be?

Comment: What does it matter if the exclamation points are escaped as well? Both `\!` and `!` will match `!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to define the characters you want to split on.

I assume you may want to keep those exclamation marks. If this is the case..

```
>>> s = "Hello(There|World!!"
>>> re.split(r'[(|]+', s)
['Hello', 'There', 'World!!']
```

If you want to split on the exclamation marks as well.

```
>>> s = "Hello(There|World!!"
>>> re.split(r'[(|!]+', s)
['Hello', 'There', 'World', '']
```

If you want to split on other characters, simply keep adding them to your class.

```
>>> s = "Hello(There|World!!Hi[There]"
>>> re.split(r'[(|!\[\]]+', s)
['Hello', 'There', 'World', 'Hi', 'There', '']
```

Then use `filter` to remove the None elements in the list.

Comment: What if I want to split on a square bracket `[` or `]`?

Comment: You can add them to the class, `re.split(r'[(|!\[\]]+', s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 re.split(r"\(|\||!",x)

Output:['Hello', 'There', 'World', '', '']
```

You can split using multiple delimiters.

Comment: You can - but you'd normally use a character class than or'ing

Comment: @JonClements This gives a better control.here we can split using !! as well which would not e possible in character class.

Comment: it's perfectly possible in a character class

Comment: @JonClements how can we achieve it using character class?

Comment: Just use `re.split('[(|!]+', 'Hello(There|World!!')` - I've added the `+` to group consecutive delimiters so you'll end up with `'Hello', 'There', 'World', '']` instead

Comment: As my answer states =)

Comment: yeah quite a sync you two got :)